# My backend django image is not getting collected by Vue. The image also doesn't get downloaded when I try to download it using the django admin portal

Tags: python, django, django-views

[This is the response I get after I try to open/download the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TOq8k.png)
[THIS IS THE DJANGO ADMIN Portal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9SNJd.png)

Please help me with my doubt as whenever I try to download/open the file it doesn't work. After this step, I am supposed to connect it with my frontend but it's not working correctly and I suspect it is because the server is not able to read it. Thank you

I tried to make a few changes like adding os.environ['DJANGO_SSL_DISABLE'] = '1' in my setting.py, didn't help. I was expecting to see the image appearing when I clicked the link